# Double Slit Experiment with Slits at Different Distances from Light Source

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In all descriptions of the double slit experiment I have seen the slits were mirror-symmetric to a hypothetical plane that is orthogonal to the slits and contains the light-source.

> Question:
>   have any experiments been conducted or can it be predicted, how the intereference pattern changes
>
> - if the distance of one of the slits from the light source is changed in a direction that is orthogonal to the original containing plane?
> - if the light source is moved parallel to the plane that contains the slits?
>
> or, for short, if the setup is asymmetric in some or several aspects?

The essence is the question, how the time-difference until the photons arrive at the slits, affects the outcome of the experiment.

Comment: Does rotating the slits/grating so that the light does not hit at 90° count?

Comment: @Jasper yes, that also counts as it effectively changes the distance to the slits and is equivalent to moving the light source parallel to the plane containing the slits.